# How can I disable trending searches in Desktop Chrome (Win 10)?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, desktop, autocomplete, google-search

When I click on the Google address bar in a new tab, it automatically and immediately displays **trending searches**, like this:

[image: picture of google trending searches on Chrome Desktop on Windows 10]

How can I disable this feature?

I know it is possible to disable trending searches on Google App on Android. I would like to also disable it on my Chrome in Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a setting at internal URL chrome://settings/syncSetup called "Autocomplete searches and URLs" which disables trending search from appearing when you click on the address bar, whilst retaining suggested autocompletes below the address bar, based on history.

[image]

Tested on Chrome Version 87.0.4280.141 (Official Build) (64-bit)