# How do I get rid of Trending Searches in Firefox Desktop when using Google search engine?

Tags: firefox, search

[image]**N.B.** - Trending searches are **not** the same as search suggestions.  Search suggestions happen when you type in a term like "dance" and it finds various dance-related terms to search on.   Trending searches is what *everyone else* is searching on at this moment -  usually things in the news headlines, celebrity stuff and other uselessness.

I don't have this problem on Chrome, only on Firefox.   In another thread someone suggested running AdBlock Plus, but I'm running that, turned up to the max, and it makes no difference.   OS is Windows 10.  Latest version of Firefox.

EDIT: added image

Comment: OK, I added an example.    Notice that the Trending Searches is even called "Trending Searches"   ... not sure what you mean by "bar"  - I get the trending searches as soon as I go to the Google Home page.   I only get search suggestions if I start trping.

Comment: Thanks. See answer.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be talking about these.
[image]
There aren't a feature of Firefox; They're a feature of Google.com.

The solution is simple. If you want to use Google in Firefox without seeing the Trending searches, then use it from either the top bar on any page that you've got open or use the handy search bar that's on Firefox's default homepage.
[image]

Comment: So you're saying if I want to use the Google home page there's no way to turn it off in Firefox?     Then why don't I get it in Chrome on the Google home page?

Comment: @user316117 Are you sure that Chrome's home page is actually the same as the google.com page that you're seeing on Firefox?

Comment: Yes, but Chrome has a setting for this.   See [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1618777/how-can-i-disable-trending-searches-in-desktop-chrome-win-10)   ..  So I wanted to know what the setting was in Firefox

Comment: @user316117 I wouldn't expect Firefox to have a setting specific to Google.com. The trending searches are already disabled in Firefox's top bar. Just use that.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Firefox 118, you will be/are able to disable Trending Searches from your search suggestions by:

1. Hover your mouse over a search term and click the menu button that will appear on the right-hand side.
2. Select the "Don't show trending searches" option.

[image]

Source: [Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-google-trending-search-firefox-address-bar#w_disable-google-trending-search)